# use a named_scope to select according to a count value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For example, say I have something like BlogCategory which has a HABTM with BlogPost, and I want to select only the BlogCategories that have actually been used in a BlogPost

```
named_scope :published, {
  :include    => :blog_posts,
  :select     => 'blog_categories.*, count(blog_posts.id) as post_count',
  :group      => 'blog_categories.id having post_count > 0',
  :conditions => 'blog_posts.published = 1',
}
```

Problem I'm having is that the :select part of this seems to be getting completely ignored by rails, so the count field doesn't get put into the query, and I end up with the error "Unknown column 'post_count' in 'having clause'"

Comment: 2.3.11 makethismorethan15chars

Comment: I don't know why what you have up there isn't working. However, as an alternative you could use a counter_cache in the belongs_to declaration and obviate the need to do a count. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't recognize post_count but it should work with:

```
  :group      => 'blog_categories.id having count(blog_posts.id) > 0',
```

Comment: good call, might be able to do away with the :select entirely. still wonder why it's being ignored though

Comment: Shoot, then I get multiples of the same BlogCategory in the results. Not what I want.

Comment: oop, never mind. I had changed something else and forgot about it. This might do the job, let me try again.

Comment: So did you remove the select too? I am just wondering about what was changed. http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/sql-having-clause-in-rails-activerecord

Comment: I was trying something using :joins instead of :include

Comment: Yep, this looks to be doing what I'm after!

Comment: BTW - Rails 3 has a much cleaner solution for this.